# @value not reading value test properties from spring boot 1.4

Tags: spring-boot

I am running integration test in spring boot, @value is always picking the property value from src/main/resources/application.properties. It needs to read the value from scr/test/resources/application.properties if i am running the integreation test.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ServiceConfig.class}) 
@SpringBootTest() 
@ActiveProfiles("test") 
public class RequestServiceSTTest { 

    @Autowired
    private RequestService irServ;

    @Test(priority = 0, description = "Request By Id")
    public void testCreateRequest() {
        irServ.createInvestmentRequest(tempIr);
        Assert.assertEquals(newIr.getType(), "Test"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a typo in your question or in the code? `scr/test/resources/application.properties` should start with **src** not scr

Comment: yes, its typo mistake

Comment: Please update your question with snippets of your integration test setup.
Reference: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have updated in the below comment, some how the code is not aligned properly, kindly help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#__testpropertysource) out

**The following example demonstrates how to declare a properties file from the classpath.**

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")
public class MyIntegrationTests {
    // class body...
}
```

> Test property sources have higher precedence than those loaded from
>   the operating system’s environment or Java system properties as well
>   as property sources added by the application declaratively via
>   @PropertySource or programmatically. Thus, test property sources can
>   be used to selectively override properties defined in system and
>   application property sources. Furthermore, inlined properties have
>   higher precedence than properties loaded from resource locations.

Comment: Thanks Nilsson, But this code is read the values in MyIntegrationTests  class only, My controller / service layer is having @value which needs reads from test/resource folder instead of main/resource while executing integration test.

Comment: Yes, I still think this is valid, have you seen my comment on your question?

Comment: If it is valid, can you please help me in how load the property from test/resources at service layer while doing integration test
Sample code,  this cost.limit should be loaded from test/resources/applicaton.properties

public class RequestService {
@Value("${cost.limit}")
 private float costLimit;

Comment: Im starting to think that you don't do your integration testing like spring describes [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing-overview)
Can you provide snippets of your integration test setup? Config and how you run it?

Comment: @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ServiceConfig.class})
@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class RequestServiceSTTest {
 @Autowired
 private RequestService irServ;
 @Test(priority = 0, description = "Request By Id")
 public void testCreateRequest() {
  irServ.createInvestmentRequest(tempIr);
  Assert.assertEquals(newIr.getType(), "Test");
 }

Comment: Service class is 
public class RequestService {
 @Value("${cost.limit}")
 private float costLimit;
}

Comment: i have this cost.limit properties in both src/main/resources/application.properties and scr/test/resources/application.properties  , while doing normal execution it reading properly from main/resources, So i am expecting it should read from test/resources while running integration test, thanks in advance.